# Mongoid: Caching Eager Loaded Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, mongoid

We have this code:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :band
end

@bands = Band.includes(:albums).entries
```

This is great because now I can run `@bands.first.albums` without hitting the DB.
But now, if we write this includes to the rails cache...

```
Rails.cache.write('bands', @bands)
```

...we then read the cache.

```
bands = Rails.cache.read('bands')
```

This returns an array of band documents...

`[#<Band _id: 536a53c969702d208f240000, created_at: 2014-05-07 15:39:53 UTC, updated_at: 2014-05-08 15:55:29 UTC, name: "Pink Floyd", fan_count: 394857, #<Band _id: 536adf2a69702d1574130000, created_at: 2014-05-08 01:34:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-05-08 01:35:40 UTC, name: "Tool", fan_count: 2958394, #<Band _id: 536bcad169702d743e1e0000, created_at: 2014-05-08 18:20:01 UTC, updated_at: 2014-05-08 18:27:10 UTC, name: "My Morning Jacket", fan_count: 3945734]`

...and then we can't get the albums.

```
bands.first.albums

NoMethodError: undefined method 'albums' for #<Array:0x00000104df50c0>
```

Is there a special way to cache these eager loaded documents with Rails or Mongoid?

FYI we're using Mongoid 4.

Comment: What is the content of `Rails.cache.read('bands')` ? is that an array of arrays? Can you inspect that element and post the result?

Comment: thats super weird. when you do `bands.first`, it returns the same array?

Comment: @ArthurNeves: No, when I run bands.first, it returns the first band fine. But I can't run bands.first.albums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like to be a eager load issue on Mongoid.. Can you go to https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/new and open a new issue, so we can work on a fix for it, before releasing the final 4.0.0 version.

thanks